# Finding nearest distance between me and friends

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

I need to find nearest location of arraylist of location in android.now i have my current location i mean latitude,longitude and set of friends locations. i need to find which friend is nearest to me? can anyone suggest me the way how to do this in android?

Answer (score 0):

Use Location class. It has a method called `distanceTo(Location loc)` to calculate the distance between two Locations.

```
Location myLocation = new Location("LocProvider");
myLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
myLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

//Same as above, Setup friendLocation 

float distance = myLocation.distanceTo(friendLocation);
```

Doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)

Comment: comparing with set of my friends location

Comment: repeat the logic in a loop against all your friend locations and find the shortest distance to get the friend who is close to you.

Comment: can you give sample code

Comment: Just iterate the set and find the shortest!